# Is there a setting to allow folders to be uploaded from a PC/Mac to an Android phone via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, macos, ftp

Reason I ask is because I get an error message saying that the type is not acceptable/supported when I attempt to drag and drop a folder into the window on my Mac showing the contents of my Android SD card.

Using Astro Bluetooth on Sony Z1 Compact, latest Android. Mac OS Mavericks.

Looked around here on SE but couldn't find an answer that addresses this issue with folders.

Comment: I don't think Android's MTP protocol supports creating folders in the root of `/sdcard`.  I could be COMPLETELY wrong though, and I encourage people to correct me!  

Have you tried creating a folder manually (right click>new folder), and then just copying the files to the folder?

All of this is me speaking out of my butt though, because I haven't used my Mac for anything Android related.  I use my PC instead...

Comment: I believe the feature I'm using uses OBEX FTP - FTP does support folders so would have thought it ought to work. Thanks for the suggestion of creating a folder - the contents contain subfolders etc so this wouldn't suit my needs. Not sure, in 2014, why support for folders would seem to be problematic, nor can I see why it would present any issues, e.g. security etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called AirDroid which allows me to upload folders/files to my Android phone. It is not done via bluetooth, however. It's done through my 4G connection.